# Running tasks sequentially in dag in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I need to run the tasks in the dag sequentially, but so that if the previous one takes the failed value, then the next task will start. That is, so that the startup does not stop after the failed task, but continues to work and check the rest.
Please tell me how this can be implemented in python code?

Approximately how the launch in airflow should look like.
[task running in airflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXCv0.png)

I've tried to look for the information in the Internet but didn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should be able to accomplish this with the trigger_rule `all_done`.

In your Airflow task set the parameter `trigger_rule` (which is a BaseOperator parameter, which means all operators should be able to use it) to all_done like this:

```py
t1 = MyOperator(
    task_id="task_1",
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    ...
)
```

or if you are using decorators:

```py
@task(
    trigger_rule="all_done"
)
def my_task():
    ...
```

This means this task will run once all upstream tasks have finished running but wont care whether they failed or not. You can find a list of all trigger rules in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules).